# Who decided that the fighters should stabilize their rear deflectors?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, a-new-hope

During the trench runs by Gold Squardon on the Death Star, one of the Gold Squadron groups begins their attack run and is attacked by Darth Vader and his TIE-fighter group.

However, the Rebel pilots realized this before it happens:

> **Pilot A:** The guns... they've stopped...
>
> **Pilot B:** Stabilize your rear deflectors. Watch for enemy fighters.

Since we only see Red Squadron report in, I am not sure which Gold Squadron pilot this is. A bit earlier in the run we here Gold Leader (I think):

> **Gold Leader:** How many guns do you think Gold Five?
>
> **Gold Five:** Say about twenty guns. Some on the surface, some on the tower.

However, during Gold Five's line the scene switches back to the Rebel base and we only hear him through the comm system.

To me Pilot B and Gold Five sound the same... **can we confirm that it was Gold Five who was smart enough to realize that they needed to "stabilize the rear deflectors"?**

The first quote is at about 6:35 while the second quote is at 6:15 in the video below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the original script.

> **GOLD TWO:** *The guns... they've stopped!*
>
> EXT. GOLD FIVE'S COCKPIT
>   Gold Five looks behind him.
>
> **[GOLD FIVE](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Davish_Krail)**: *Stabilize your rear deflectors. Watch   for enemy fighters.*
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope - Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html)</sup></sub>

Confirmed in the film's junior novelisation

> Suddenly, the barrage of Imperial laserfire came to an abrupt end. Baffled, Gold Two said, “The guns … they’ve stopped!”
>   Even though the three pilots were still traveling at high speed, the trench seemed eerily calm. Gold Five glanced out of his cockpit window and said, “Stabilize your rear deflectors. Watch for enemy fighters.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope (junior novelization)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Interestingly the original novelisation identifies the speaker as ***Red*** Five ("Pops") but the callsigns were switched around in the film (red became gold).

> “I don’t like it,” growled Red Leader. But there was nothing to confuse their approach now, no energy bolts to avoid.
>   It was [Pops](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Davish_Krail) who was first to properly evaluate this seeming aberration on the enemy’s part. “Stabilize your rear deflectors now. Watch for enemy fighters.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Do we have any info on who Gold 5 is?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Gold Five was [this guy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Davish_Krail).